# Dart equivalent getting index in List with for statement and .map or .forEach

Tags: flutter, dart

In this sample `for` statement, I can find out the `index` when `if` statement returns `true`:

```
final List<Cart> cart = box.values.toList();
int ix = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= cart.length - 1; i++) {
  if(cart[i].id == products[productIndex].id){
    ix = i;
  }
}
```

Now, my question is: how can I implement this code with `.map` or `.forEach`?

```
int ix = cart.forEach((cart) 
  { 
     cart.id == widget.storeCategories[index].products[productIndex].id ? ++ix:ix;
   }
);
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `.map` and `.forEach`?  If you care about an index, then `.map` and `.forEach` are inappropriate.  Use [`List.indexWhere`](https://api.dart.dev/stabledart-core/List/indexWhere.html) instead.

Comment: @jamesdlin thanks a lot. my issue solved

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
  final List<int> list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
  list.asMap().forEach((index,item){
    print("$index: $item");
  });
```